# Snackbar accessibility

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I’m using a custom snackbar with indefinite duration. I need the snackbar to get focus automatically in accessibility mode when it’s displayed. 
Please let me know if anyone knows a way of doing this.

Comment: are you trying to give focus to the default text link?

Comment: I need focus on the whole snackbar layout if possible once it appears. If not focus on the text in the snackbar also should suffice. I want the user to know that snackbar appeared when in accessibility mode.

Comment: the snackbar contains a textview.  You can get the id of it by looking for android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text.  Then you can .requestFocus(); on it, i would guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a snackbar.getView()  and set the Type_view_focused after calling show() function. Remember to put a delay after the show() to get accessibility to attach to snackar